# SafeMath reduces gas cost?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm developing a project with another guy and he was using SafeMath.

Then, I said it wasn't necessary once we use solidity version ^0.8.0, and I thought that it would reduces gas if we remove SafeMath.

However, we tested both codes with and without SafeMath. The code with SafeMath cost less gas.

It was almost the same cost, but SafeMath code used less gas.

Does it make sense? I didn't understand.

I tested both codes and SafeMath code cost less gas.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing something else affect the gas cost, like the function name. Here are two contracts with their gas cost as measured by Remix (solidity 0.8.7, optimizer not enabled). Either way, here are some benchmarks that show safemath is not more gas efficient. I think something was wrong with your tests.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract SafeMathTest {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    // 382 gas
    function a(uint256 x) external pure returns (uint256 sum) {
        sum = x.add(1);
    }

    // 327 gas
    function b(uint256 x) external pure returns (uint256 sum) {
        sum = x + 1;
    }
}

contract SafeMathTest2 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    // 372 gas
    function b(uint256 x) external pure returns (uint256 sum) {
        sum = x.add(1);
    }

    // 349 gas
    function a(uint256 x) external pure returns (uint256 sum) {
        sum = x + 1;
    }
}
```